# Create custom Range in Word Javascript API / Office.js

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I understand that many methods of the Word Javascript API return a `Range` or `RangeCollection`. But, is there a constructor function developers can use to create a new `Range` directly?

My use case is that I need to look at each paragraph, identify errors, and syntax highlight them. So, I'd like to just get the plain text of the paragraph using the API, find the errors on my own, and then use that information to create a `Range` that I can use to decorate the text (or add a Bounday/ContentControl to refer to it later).

Comment: great question. same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of options for you.

a. Use search - you can scope it to the paragraph. You can also use range.[compareLocationWith](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/reference/word/range.md#comparelocationwithrange-range) to compare if the found range is the same and remove dupes. So the idea is you grab a paragraph, analyze, find an issue, do a search to get the range (and make sure is the range you need). Once you have a range you can apply formatting, insert content controls or insert, replace content.

b. Use [split](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/reference/word/range.md#splitdelimiters-string-multiparagraphs-bool-trimdelimiters-bool-trimspacing-bool) - is a method you can use to decompose a paragraph into words (each a range).

c. ExpandTo - to extend a given range to another.

d. on any object you can use .getRange() to get its associated range.

Comment: Strange that there's no obvious way to just make a `Range`

Comment: Almost all methods on the API return a range, but curious to see what you were expecting.

Comment: Since I get the offsets in the text of the errors I want to decorate, I'd love to be able to create a range on the document via something like `var range = new Range(startOffset, endOffset);` or on the paragraph with something like `var range = paragraph.getRange(startOffset, endOffset);`

Without being able to create a range, it seems like there's no way to ever verify that the `Range` I get back from `search` or `split` are the same as the words I'd like to decorate, since I can't use `compareLocationWith` without already having a `Range` object. Catch 22.

Comment: the problem with supporting offsets and start/end positions in general  is that its a super unreliable way of referring to a range and too easily can be a broken story. This has been a historic and constant source of pain for Word developers and we explicitly decided not to support this viced design. For now you can get your range with paragraph.search()

Comment: @JuanBalmori, (1) The first link is broken for the compareLocationWith. (2) It's not clear from the answer why the compareLocationWith helps us. It would help if we had range.getStartOffset or range.getEndOffset, but we don't (3) the problem with search is that let's say you want to mark the word "the" in the offsets [100,103]. But then the user continue to write, and add the word "the" somewhere before in the text- then the .search method gets broken. if he had offsest, we could fix the offset using a diff between the old text version to the new and move the range manually.