# Word Office Javascript API - Format first x chars

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I need to change the size of the first X characters for my add-in. To do this, I should either be able to go through the individual characters or format the first X characters in one go. But I can't find a way to access the individual characters in a `Word.Range` that works on the web and also on the desktop. So far it only works via the `search` method. Have I overlooked something?

```js
// slow performance
const charRangeCollection = word.search("*", {
  matchWildcards: true,
  matchCase: false,
  ignoreSpace: true,
  ignorePunct: true,
  matchPrefix: false,
  matchSuffix: false,
  matchWholeWord: false,
});
```

This does not work with **Word under Windows**.

```js
const wordChar = wordRange.getRange().split([""]);
```

> Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: InvalidArgument

In this answer they write getTextRanges() no longer accepts empty strings, but I don't know what to pass so that I only get the characters of one word ->
[How to get a range from start & end index with Office.js while developing MS Word Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796308/how-to-get-a-range-from-start-end-index-with-office-js-while-developing-ms-wor)

Comment: I replicated this. I found this old post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916485/create-custom-range-in-word-javascript-api-office-js - comments say that the devs. decided not to allow simple indexing of Ranges, for reasons which I recognise, but they could surely have created a new Range2 object in Word to fix all that stuff.  Can't see another workaround, so stick to .search I guess. Perhaps re-open https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/390 - it *does* work on web-based Word, so why fail on Desktop Word? (fails on Mac too BTW). Don't know how long fixes take in office-js!

Comment: Please post your Office-js API related issues [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) where we check regularly. Of course, if you are not sure if it is due to wrong usage, you are also welcome to  post here.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the inconvenience. There is no other way currently. We open an internal bug #8831269 for the "Range.split([""])" consistency issues between Word Windows and Online. Thanks.

Comment: Connection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1613997/word-office-javascript-api-format-first-x-chars